# Dual monitor wallpaper issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, image-processing, extended-desktop

I have two identical Samsung monitors with resolutions set to 1920x1080. I am attempting to use a PC of 3840x1080 and span across the two. Unfortunately, regardless of the image I use I get the shear effect as in the pic.

Anyone has any idea as to why or a solution?

[image: pic of problem]

Comment: The cable connecting them to the PC are they same type. HDMI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rearrange monitors on Windows 10, use these steps:

- Open *Settings > System > Display*
- Under "Select and rearrange displays" section, drag and drop each display to
  rearrange them according to their physical layout on your desktop.
- Ensure that the monitors align at the top perfectly
- Click the Apply button.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for that. So simple yet I couldn't see it!